# Jetty 9.3.8.v20160314 rejects TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 but not TLSv1.2 connections

Tags: ssl, jetty

Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-91-generic x86_64)

java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Jetty 9.3.8.v2016031 connector configured like below:

```
SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(sslKeystore);
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword(SystemUtils.getEnvOrThrow("SERVER_SSL_PASSWORD"));
sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword(SystemUtils.getEnvOrThrow("SERVER_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD"));

HttpConfiguration https_config = new HttpConfiguration();
https_config.setOutputBufferSize(32768);
https_config.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

ServerConnector https = new ServerConnector(
    server,
    new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"),
    new HttpConnectionFactory(https_config));

https.setPort(Integer.valueOf(SystemUtils.getEnvOrThrow("SERVER_SSL_PORT")));
https.setIdleTimeout(60000);

server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { https });
```

I can make TLSv1.2 connections:

```
curl -X "GET" "https://<hidden_hostname>/some/path" -v --tlsv1.2

* Connected to <hidden_hostname> (123.45.67.890) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

but when I try TLSv1.0 or TLSv1.1 I get this:

```
curl -X "GET" "https://<hidden_hostname>/some/path" -v --tlsv1.0

* Connected to <hidden_hostname> (123.45.67.890) port 443 (#0)
* Server aborted the SSL handshake
```

List of enabled and supported protocols is:

```
Enabled protocol: SSLv2Hello
Enabled protocol: TLSv1
Enabled protocol: TLSv1.1
Enabled protocol: TLSv1.2

Supported protocol: SSLv2Hello
Supported protocol: SSLv3
Supported protocol: TLSv1
Supported protocol: TLSv1.1
Supported protocol: TLSv1.2
```

And I don't know where the problem lies.
I have some clients which cannot use anything other than TLSv1.0.

**Update 1 - added sslscan output**

```
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  AECDH-AES256-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ADH-AES256-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  ADH-AES256-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  AES256-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  CAMELLIA256-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  168 bits  SRP-DSS-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  168 bits  SRP-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  168 bits  SRP-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  AECDH-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  168 bits  PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  AECDH-AES128-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ADH-AES128-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ADH-AES128-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ADH-SEED-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ADH-CAMELLIA128-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  AES128-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  SEED-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  CAMELLIA128-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  AECDH-RC4-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ADH-RC4-MD5
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  RC4-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  RC4-MD5
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  PSK-RC4-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  56 bits   EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  56 bits   EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  56 bits   ADH-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  56 bits   DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  40 bits   EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  40 bits   EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  40 bits   EXP-ADH-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  40 bits   EXP-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  40 bits   EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5
Rejected  SSLv3  40 bits   EXP-ADH-RC4-MD5
Rejected  SSLv3  40 bits   EXP-RC4-MD5
Rejected  SSLv3  0 bits    ECDHE-RSA-NULL-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  0 bits    ECDHE-ECDSA-NULL-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  0 bits    AECDH-NULL-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  0 bits    ECDH-RSA-NULL-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  0 bits    ECDH-ECDSA-NULL-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  0 bits    NULL-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  0 bits    NULL-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  0 bits    NULL-MD5
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  AECDH-AES256-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ADH-AES256-SHA256
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  ADH-AES256-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA256
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  CAMELLIA256-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  168 bits  ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  168 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  168 bits  SRP-DSS-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  168 bits  SRP-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  168 bits  SRP-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  168 bits  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  168 bits  EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  168 bits  AECDH-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  168 bits  ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  168 bits  ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  168 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  168 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  168 bits  PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  AECDH-AES128-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ADH-AES128-SHA256
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ADH-AES128-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ADH-SEED-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ADH-CAMELLIA128-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-SHA256
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  SEED-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  CAMELLIA128-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  AECDH-RC4-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ADH-RC4-MD5
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-MD5
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  PSK-RC4-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  56 bits   EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  56 bits   EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  56 bits   ADH-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  56 bits   DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  40 bits   EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  40 bits   EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  40 bits   EXP-ADH-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  40 bits   EXP-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  40 bits   EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5
Rejected  TLSv1  40 bits   EXP-ADH-RC4-MD5
Rejected  TLSv1  40 bits   EXP-RC4-MD5
Rejected  TLSv1  0 bits    ECDHE-RSA-NULL-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  0 bits    ECDHE-ECDSA-NULL-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  0 bits    AECDH-NULL-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  0 bits    ECDH-RSA-NULL-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  0 bits    ECDH-ECDSA-NULL-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  0 bits    NULL-SHA256
Rejected  TLSv1  0 bits    NULL-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  0 bits    NULL-MD5
```

**Update 2 - more detailed curl output**

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 123.45.67.890...
* Connected to <hidden_hostname> (123.45.67.890) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to <hidden_hostname>:443
* Closing connection 0
  curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to <hidden_hostname>:443
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLSv1.0 is considered insecure and vulnerable.

The default configuration on Jetty (and some versions of Java) has the needed ciphers for TLS 1.0 disabled.

Here's how you can fix it in the short term.

> **Note:** once TLS 1.3 is a reality, and Java supports it, then even this short term fix will not be possible, as TLS 1.3 has plans to outright ban known vulnerable Ciphers from being present for any support level.
>
> You really need to upgrade those clients soon, otherwise you'll be stuck on old java, old jetty, and even old OS installations with no valid option to upgrade any of those.

First, your `SslContextFactory` has a [declared set of exclude ciphers](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.10.v20160621/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory.java#L253-L256), you'll need to adjust those exclusions to fit your environment the best way possible.

You can do this by redeclaring your excluded ciphers.

```java
SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
sslContextFactory.setExcludeCipherSuites(
            "SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
            "SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA");
```

If this still doesn't help you, then you likely also have Java level disabled ciphers.

Check the `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` file for any configurations that are disabling "ciphers" or "algorithms" (the name can vary depending on your choice of JVM)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the risk with this approach. Thank you for your help. I will give it a try and I will let you know.

Comment: As a fast workaround I have added sslContextFactory.setExcludeCipherSuites() and it works. In the future I will try to update the clients. Thank you.